# It is not possible to pack Android 12 Automotive AVD with provided scripts

Tags: android, linux, android-source, ramdisk, android-automotive

I correctly built an Android 12 Automotive Emulator (in a Linux build server, thus I couldn't even launch it) without issues.
Now I need to pack, download and share it with colleagues as we did so far with Android 10 and 11.

I discovered there is a new make command "emu_img_zip" which should do it. Unfortunately when I launch the command it fails soon because ramdisk file is missing. Here the output:

> $ m emu_img_zip

> build/make/core/soong_config.mk:195: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated.
> Use SYSTEM_EXT_PUBLIC_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
> build/make/core/soong_config.mk:196: warning: BOARD_PLAT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIR has been deprecated. Use SYSTEM_EXT_PRIVATE_SEPOLICY_DIRS instead.
> ============================================
> PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
> PLATFORM_VERSION=12
> TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_car_x86_64
> TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
> TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
> TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
> TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
> TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
> TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
> HOST_ARCH=x86_64
> HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
> HOST_OS=linux
> HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-204-generic-x86_64-Ubuntu-16.04.7-LTS
> HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
> HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
> HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
> HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
> BUILD_ID=SSV1.210916.026
> OUT_DIR=out
> PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES=device/generic/goldfish device/generic/goldfish-opengl hardware/google/camera hardware/google/camera/devices/EmulatedCamera
> ============================================
> FAILED: ninja: 'out/target/product/generic_car_x86_64/ramdisk-qemu.img', needed by 'out/target/product/generic_car_x86_64/emulator/x86_64/ramdisk.img', missing and no known rule to make it
> 15:39:01 ninja failed with: exit status 1

> ##### failed to build some targets (6 seconds)

The same happens if I try to generate the AVD creating the SDK (this is what we did so far with previous Android versions) by means of "make sdk sdk_repo" command

I also noticed kernel-ranchu is missing and also other stuff like vendor.img in out directory

Anyone experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a different lunch command should be used.

After doing *lunch sdk_car_x86_64-userdebug* and building with *make*, all the images are generated and it is possibile to pack them using *m emu_img_zip*. It is also possibile to generate the SDK.

[A similar post can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69532499/userdata-image-not-generated-after-aosp-build-for-car)